# How to open an existing project in .net c# in Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I already have a project folder, with relevant files inside. I need to change the working directory in Visual studio to this project folder, I just can't find how to do it in Visual studio.

It seems I can only create a new project or open a solution file, but not set the working directory to the folder I want and start work on existing project. There is no solution file in the folder too.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Are you asking "how can I open a .csproj file if I don't have a .sln file"?  Otherwise, can you describe what's in the "existing project"?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the project to a new folder, and re-add it to your solution.

Comment: I tried this with not good results, Isnt there a way to simply specify the working directory in Visual studio 2008?

Comment: @LS: No, this is the easiest. There is nothing tricky about it.